# UITableView copyWithZone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a timer and I can't figure out what I did wrong.
Here is the code where I think something is going wrong:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var laps: [String] = []

    var minutes = 0
    var fractions = 0
    var seconds = 0
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var timerIsOn = false
    var timerString: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var lapsTable: UITableView!

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if timerIsOn == false {


        fractions = 0
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 0
        timerLabel.text = "\(minutes):\(seconds).\(fractions)"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerIsOn = true
        }

    }




    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerIsOn = false
        laps.insert(timerString, atIndex: 0)
        lapsTable.reloadData()

    }

    func updateTimer(){
        fractions += 1
        if fractions == 100 {
            fractions = 0
            seconds += 1
        }
        if seconds == 60 {
            seconds = 0
            minutes += 1

        }

        timerLabel.text = "\(minutes):\(seconds).\(fractions)"

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor

        cell.textLabel!.text = "Solve \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = laps[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return laps.count


    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and this is the error:

> Timer[3034:273560] -[UITableView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7f893301da00 2016-10-04 15:33:34.565 Professor Cube
>   Timer[3034:273560] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView copyWithZone:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f893301da00

Please help.

Comment: It doesn't look like your problem is here.  Set an exception breakpoint to determine where the crash is occuring

Comment: I decided to put all the code here. I wasn't able to figure out the breakpoint thing. It said Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1, I don't know if that helps you.

Comment: The crash stack trace would help @Jackson

Comment: Set the style of the cell in Interface Builder and use reusable cells `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` and the table view instances in the delegate methods are non-optionals (without exclamation mark) `func tableView(tableView: UITableView,...`